# Firefox driver unable to detect webelement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to get the anchor link via WebDriver but somehow, things aren't working as desired and I am not getting the element.

Below is the HTML Structure:

```
<div id="1">
   <table width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td>.....</td>
         <td>
           <ul class="bullet">
              <li>....</li>
              <li>....</li>
              <li>
                 <a href="/abc/myText.html?asq=ahsdyrg347rfbwljidwbkjab">myText</a>
              </li> // myText is the text I am searching for
           </ul>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>....</div>
</div>
```

The `<li>` elements contains anchor tags with links only. No `id` or any other attribute they contain. The only difference is the text displayed by them and hence, I am passing `myText` to detect exactly what I need.

And for this, the java code I have been trying is:

```
   driver.get("url");

   Thread.sleep()    //waiting for elements to get loaded. Exceptional Handling not done.
   WebElement divOne = driver.findElement(By.id("1"));

   WebElement ul = divOne.findElement(By.className("bullet"));

  WebElement anchor = null;
    try{ 
        anchor = ul.findElement(By.partialLinkText("myText"));
    }catch(NoSuchElementException ex){
        LOGGER.warn("Not able to locate tag:" + linkText + "\n");
    }
   String myLink = anchor.getAttribute("href");   // null pointer exception
```

I don't understand why is this happening. What is the correct way to do this? Should I use some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any of the below. Should work for you

```
List<WebElement> anchor = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("myText"));
```

or

```
driver.findElements(By.linkText("myText"))
```

or

```
driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//a[contains(text(),'myText')]"));
```

Comment: didn't i use  `partialLinkText` ?

Comment: Yes. Please use the "findElements" with driver instance and take it in a list then get the 0th element. or you can use the Xpath also. This should work.

Comment: The Xpath version doesn't give me the complete URL. It is giving something like `http://demowebsite.com/?asq=ahsdyrg347rfbwljidwbkjab` . There is no "myText" in the link as it is in the HTML.

Comment: This is how I am using Xpath  `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),"+linkText+")]")).get(0)` , where linkText is nothing but myText passed in method parameter.

Comment: Change to this, added single quote. you can also try with double quote with escape character driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'"+linkText+"')]")).get(0)

Comment: Actually, myText is a country name, and which is present in many different lines in the html, but I need the exact which is mentioned within <li> above, that is why i hopped to that link and tried, but with Xpath, its giving me some other link (which also contains that country name)

Comment: Can you use more specific xpath . Something like below. It says give me the elements which are inside the div with id 1 and under Ul/li/a.                                     driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//div[@id = 1]//ul/li/a[contains(text(),'myText')]"));

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'myTest')]"));
```

that searches for myTest text. I haven't tried the code, I hope it helps you

Comment: No, its giving me some other link which also contains 'myText'. I need the link within that <li> tag.

Comment: in the same div? because if its in a different div, you can do something like "//div[@id='1']//a[contains(text(),'myTest')]"

Answer (score 0):

```
String myLink = anchor.getAttribute("href");   // null pointer exception
```

You are getting exception because you didn't set the anchor value, anchor variable is created and intialized to null and after that it is never updated.

I think the correct code should be below

```
String myLink = element.getAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `WebDriver` instance directly instead of `WebElement` instance...i.e., use `driver` instead of `ul`..

you can try with wait,

```
element = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("myText")));
```